# error 400 in vba-excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm fairly new to vba and i don't understand why i'm getting error 400.

I'm having this list. When i push the button, this list has to be deleted, you have to select a file and then the new list will be copied from this file to the list. The list is always the same amount of columns (A-J), variable in length (rows) so in column K i can put a formula to test some data in the list according to data on another sheet.

The problem is with the vba-line

```
.Sheets("Blad1").UsedRange.Copy LijstBP.Sheets("Blad1").Range("A1")
```

To test my code, I used a list on sheet "Blad2". My code works perfect with all lists i'm trying to copy. (ofcourse i had to change the code to "Blad2")
Now,  the new lists are on sheet "Blad1". I only changed "Blad2" into "Blad1" and the error occurs...

Someone can spread a light on this? Thanks. 
My entire code is:

```
Sub ImporteerData()
Dim LijstBP As Workbook
Dim Bron As Workbook
Set LijstBP = ActiveWorkbook

Call WisHuidigeLijst

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .Sheets("Blad1").UsedRange.Copy LijstBP.Sheets("Blad1").Range("A1")
            .Close False
        End With
    End If
End With
'Formule kopiëren
Set LijstBP = ActiveWorkbook
Range("K3").FillDown
End Sub

Private Sub WisHuidigeLijst()
Dim laatsteRij As Integer

laatsteRij = Cells(3, "A").End(xlDown).Row
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select

Range("A1:J" & laatsteRij).Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Does BLAD1 occur in both opened workbook and workbook to copy to?

Comment: Also change Dim laatsteRij As Integer to Dim laatsteRij As Long

Comment: Have you tried making `Blad1` the ActiveSheet before copying?

Comment: Hi, Blad1 does Occur in both the opened workbook and workbook to copy to. I changed de Dim laatseRij to  Long, but this doesn't affect the problem.

I added
    Worksheets("Blad1").Activate

right after the "With ActiveWorkbook"

Now i get an error 1004 on the same line

Comment: Perhaps a trailing space in the name of "Blad 1", like this: "Blad 1 "

Comment: @Luuklag: i checked the spelling, but everything seems correct.
After a few tries I still get errormessage 400...

Comment: Try splitting your copy and paste actions into two rows of code, see which of the two errors out.

Comment: @Luuklag  this is how i was thinking, but i don't have a clue how to do it, without working with 3dimensional arrays or working with a lot of Objects. Any proposal?
I don't want the code to get too difficult, because it works on the testfiles, which are basicly the same files on another sheet...

Comment: `LijstBP.Sheets("Blad1").Range("A1").pastespecial(4104)`

Comment: I just solved the problem:
My collegue, who makes the lists that i need to import, did something wrong: he created a list from columns A-I instead of A-J. By creating a new list from A-J, the whole thing works.
My apologies for bothering with such stupidity :-) Last week, i didn't notice this.
Thanks to all for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem: My collegue, who makes the lists that i need to import, did something wrong: he created a list from columns A-I instead of A-J. By creating a new list from A-J, the whole thing works. My apologies for bothering with such stupidity :-) Last week, i didn't notice this. Thanks to all for trying to help me. –